# Como colocar imagens na tela?

Tags: c, api, gráfico

No MSX, você usava BASIC pra colocar uma imagem na tela sem sair do modo de linhas de comando.
Hoje, não conseguimos mais fazer isso? Sem usar OpenGL ou outras APIs, como fazer para colocar pixels na tela? Ou uma imagem inteira? Tem que mandar pra VRAM?
É que só aprendemos a exibir textos no DOS do PC.

Answer (score 1):

Não - hoje em dia, em PCs normais não tem como fazer isso.
Acotnece que desde a especificação do VGA do PC original aconteceram duas coisas que impedem que você simplesmente possa copiar alguns bytes parauma região de memória e ver isso na tela:

1) Uma fragmentação das especificações de modos de vídeo: depois do VGA nunca mias houve um modo unificado de vídeo, que funcionasse em todas as placas. Cada fabricante, alias cada placa de vídeo, tinha (e de certa forma ainda tem) formas específicas de endereçar a memória de vídeo, modos de vídeo, etc... Depois que as placas de vídeo ultrapassaram o VGA, e antes do Windows ser a interface dominante para o vídeo, houve uma época emq ue cada programa gráfico tinha que trazer, dentro de si mesm, os drivers para diferentes placas de vídeo

2) Com a maior capacidade dos computadores (PCs), o Sistema Operacional passou a assumir mais seriamente sue papel, até então meio teórico nos PCs, de abstrair a parte de hardware: os porgramas não precisavam mais se preocupar com a placa de vídeo instalada, e usavam APIs do sistema operacional para desenhar na tela.  Com uma chamada ao sistema, o programa descobre a largura  altura da tela em pixels. Se a placa de vídeo não tivesse todas as cores necessárias, era papel do S.O. - fosse o Windows, o Linux, com a camada de apresentação gráfica X11, ou outro sistema, reduzir o número de cores automaticamente. O sistema operacional tambem assume o papel de impedir que programas normais possam escrever em qualquer região da memória ou usar I/O para reconfigurar o vídeo: apenas o sistema operacional deve poder alterar as configurações de hardware - um programa não deve poder interferir nos demais programas que estão rodando.

---

Então é isso - você fica com a API Win 32 que deve permitir que você cire uma janela em tela cheia, e desenhe nessa janela. No X11, usado no Linux e em oturs Unix, você pdo desenhar na Root Window.
No Linux e outros Unixes ,sem o sistema de janelas X11, você também pdoeria usar framebuffer - ou seja,a  fragmentação continua.

Uma biblioteca que apareceu depois de um tempo, que dá uma boa mãonessa parte, nos entido de simplificar tudo, e inclusive permitir programas gráficos que rodem em tela cheia tanto no Windows quanto no Linux com ou sem X11 foi a [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) - você só precisa instalar a mesma, e os arquivos .h dela para fazer código que desenhe na tela.

No entanto - se você for no site da SDL, e procurar pelos tutoriais, vai ver que em C, mesmo usando a SDL, tem um bocado de burocracia paté você chegar no vídeo em si, e poder desenhar na tela.

Há muitos anos atrás eu me fazia a mesma pergunta que você faz agora: como eu faço para desenhar na tela, algo que só eu queira, sem janelas de outros programas, como se fazia no Basic dos computadores da década de 80?

Pra mim a resposta foi: usando a linguagem Python, e os vínculos da linguagem Python com a biblioteca SDL - esse projeto é chamado Pygame.

Se você instalar o [Python](http://www.python.org) do site oficial, e o [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org) apropriado - ambos tem instaladores para windows, vai poder escrever código desse tipo:

```
import pygame

try:
    pygame.init()
    WIDTH, HEIGHT = pygame.display.list_modes()[0]
    tela = pygame.display.set_mode((1680,1050), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    #pygame.draw.rect(tela, (255,0,0), (100,100,200,100))
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        cor = (y % 256, (y + 128) % 256, 255 - y % 256)
        pygame.draw.line(tela, cor, (0,y), (WIDTH,y))
    pygame.event.pump()
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.delay(10000)
finally:
    pygame.quit()
```

(este é o programa completo) 
O pygame também permite que você carregue arquivos de imagem do disco, responda a eventos do teclado e do mouse, dentre outras coisas - veja a documentação completa no site.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o único jeito será utilizando alguma API ou Framework, onde você deixaria de usar o terminal modo texto para rodar suas aplicações e passaria a executa-las no ambiente preparado pela API.

Você pode utilizar **GTK** ou o **Borland C++ Builder**, ou API's como o **OpenGL** e **SDL**.

```
    //Exibindo uma imagem bitmap com SDL
    SDL_Surface *image;
    SDL_Surface *temp;

    temp = SDL_LoadBMP("image.bmp");
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to load bitmap: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    image = SDL_DisplayFormat(temp);
    SDL_FreeSurface(temp);
```

Sei que não é exatamente a resposta que você gostaria, mas não conheço outro jeito.